# Using Java thread pool, how to process some messages serially and others in parallel depending on message characteristic?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is more of a Java concurrency design question. I’m working on an application that need to process many messages for many different clients. If two messages have different client names, then they can be processed in parallel. However, if they have the same client name, then they need to be processed in order serially.

What’s the best way to implement this?

My current implementation is pretty simple: I wrote a wrapper class called OrderedExecutorPool. It has a list of single-threaded executors. In its submit method, it does the following to figure out which executor to submit the task to:

```
int executorNum = Math.abs(clientName.hashCode()) % numExecutors;
executorList.get(executorNum).submit(task);
```

This ensures that all messages with same clients go to the same executor while still supporting processing messages for different clients in parallel.

There are a couple of problems with this design:

1.) If most client names have same hash code, then only a few executors are doing work

2.) If one client has MANY messages, only one executor may not keep up

Is there an elegant solution to this problem that can fix the shortcomings above?

**Edit**
clientName is just a String. I'm just invoking the String.hashCode() method on it.

Comment: are you overloading hashCode with a sensible method?   
Does it guarantee that you always will return unique values for unique strings?  
Are you sure that you will ALWAYS have less than 2^32 unique client-names (hence hashcodes)? 
Are you sure that your current hashCode-implementation is collision-free?    

If you answer "no" to ANY of these questions ... you're making a mistake and your application will crash / yield false results at some point.

Comment: "If one client has MANY messages, only one executor may not keep up"  given your requirement for a single client to process serially the only choice is to do less work, or make it more efficient.

Comment: Note: Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) < 0. You can use an `&` instead. e.g. `(clientName.hashCode() & Integer.MIN_VALUE) % numExecutors;` or if numExecutors is a power of 2 `clientName & (numExecutors - 1);`

Comment: @specializt, What would happen if two different client names produced the same hash code?  It looks to me as if their tasks would always be submitted to the same single-threaded executor service.  How will that crash the app?

Comment: implementation-dependent. In most cases, you will have yourself a few serious errors - all of which are nigh-untraceable unless you put transactions and audit-logs on EVERYTHING.

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify that clientName is just a String. I definitely have less than 2^32 unique clients, fortunately. Doesn't String.hashCode() generate pretty uniformly distributed hash values?

Answer (score 0):

There is no jdk builtin solution that i know of.  i've implemented a custom executor solution to this at my current job using this basic logic.

- keep an internal map of clientname to work queue (each client has their own queue)
- when work comes in for a client, add it to their queue

  - if this is the first job on the queue, create a Runnable for this clientname/queue and push it into the "real" executor (standard jdk thread pool)
- Runnable impl just consumes tasks from a single client queue until empty and then exits

this simple implementation is the "greedy" approach (a client will keep working until its queue is empty).  if you have more clients than underlying threads, you may want a more "fair" approach, where a client executes some number of tasks and they re-queues itself in the underlying executor (thus allowing other clients to get some work done).